# How do I not have +0j appear in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, math

I am trying to have math equations not end up with +0j at the end.
This is what I currently have

```
from cmath import sqrt
a = int(input("insert number: "))
b = int(input("insert number: "))
exp = input("Would you like to have exponents? ")
function = input("Put what kind of equasion you want: ")
if function == "*" or "multiplication" or "MULTIPLICATION" or "Multiplication":
    if exp == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
        e = int(input("What number do you want?"))
        root = input("Would you like square root? ")
        if root == "yes":
            c = int(sqrt(a * b))
            d = c ** e
            print(a, "was", function, "by", b, "getting the answer of", c)
        print("Then", c, "was put to the power of", e, "giving the final answer of", d)
```

When I run it, the final number (which appears where variable d is) ends up have a +0J at the end. What would I need to add or remove to get that to not happen? I was told it might be something with the `function` variable I have that is causing the problem but I am not sure how I could get the `function` out of a string.

Comment: So don't use a complex number? `+ 0j` is part of the string representation of `complex`  instances

Comment: it depends what you enter, `+0j` is a complex number, debug the code to determine when a result gets complex

Comment: Side note: [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503)

Comment: @rioV8 `cmath.sqrt` returns  a `complex` instance (guess what the `c` in `cmath` stands for :) )

Comment: @DeepSpace where would ```cmath.sqrt``` go?

Comment: `d` does not have a value in all paths.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp kind of, I just need to know where the ```cmath.sqrt``` would go

Comment: @rioV8 how does ```d``` not have a value?

Comment: Why not use `math` instead of `cmath`?

Comment: @JohnColeman where would ```math``` go?

Comment: I figured out where ```math``` would go

Comment: You could simply delete the character `c` in `from cmath import sqrt`.

Comment: find all the paths of your program and determine if all variables have a valid value